# how to fix this 404 error in django urlconfig patterns

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a basic app in my Django project. I mapped the views to url. While running this project it is showing

> 404 page not found.

## in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path(' ',views.index,name="index"),
]
```

## in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world");
```

## in project/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include,path
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    path("myapp/ ",include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I expect the output to be like hello world
[image]

Comment: Which URL is showing 404?

Comment: You sure you're trying to access `localhost:(your port)/myapp/`?

Comment: This seems to be your app's urls.py can you show projects urls.py. Seems like you forgot to update projects' urls.py

Comment: I edited this question @heemayl and added a image description

Comment: @Ausaf i included my app.urls in my project.urls

Comment: @Paolo C:\Users\Monica.R\Desktop\djangogirls\myfirstproject>python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 1):

Remove space character form your patters

In `urls.py` change

`path(' ',views.index,name="index")` to `path('',views.index,name="index")`

In `project/urls.py` change

`path("myapp/ ",include('myapp.urls')),` to `path("myapp/",include('myapp.urls')),`